# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes at shutdown

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, freeze

I have just installed **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** on my **UX550VD ASUS laptop** alongside Windows, dual boot, but when I am unable to shutdown or restart the machine and Ubuntu **freezes** when I try to shutdown from terminal or GUI and when I press  <kbd>**ESC**</kbd> for more information on the error nothing happens and I am still stuck on ubuntu desktop.

Last year I had the exact same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 on another machine  but removing windows and installing Ubuntu again solved my problem then.

I would be very grateful if you could help me :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same issue with both Ubuntu and Kubuntu 18.04.3 LTS versions. The problem begins immediately you perform the first update after a fresh install. I realized that it was a graphics related issue and added the oibaf ppa to the list of repositories as shown below

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

After several days and several updates the problem was solved. Now my Kubuntu installation no longer freezes on shutdown and powers down the machine completely

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with the graphic driver. Installing NVIDIA drivers solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a problem with the graphic driver. Installing NVIDIA drivers solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for the reboot freeze- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1756226/comments/20

Using Asus ROG GL752-VW, NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 960M. Also currently using nvidia-driver-390 instead of Nouveau. Running dual booted Win10 and Ubuntu Mate 18.04.

In addition for the shutdown issue, used Lekensteyn's answer in this link - https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/764#issuecomment-234494238 (Lekensteyn commented on Jul 22, 2016)