# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS not shutting down or rebooting after update

Tags: kubuntu, shutdown, reboot

I noticed that after updating Ubuntu and Kubuntu 18.04.3 LTS for the very first time after installation my pc does not power down after shutting down or rebooting. The mouse remains on, the numlock key(does not go off when I toggle the numlock key) as well and I still hear the fans humming. It kind of "freezes" and I have to manually hold the power button or switch off from the wall socket so that the machine can power down. What's the solution to this problem?

Comment: It is not related to `ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: The behaviour started after installing them. Took me some time to realize after doing several installations

Comment: @Pilot6 You are right. I redid a fresh installation and this time observed more carefully and realized that the problem begins after updating Ubuntu 18.04.3 for the very first time

Comment: Open a terminal and write: reboot

Comment: @nano Please check answer on this link https://askubuntu.com/a/1204454/684720